# How to make navigation drawers play nicely with recyclerviews?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I've got an activity with a recyclerview and a navigation drawer.

When the drawer is in front the recyclerview and I open it it still appears behind everything.

but when the drawer is behind the recyclerview the recyclerview doesn't get any inputs and the drawer works perfectly.

[Broken Layering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9297Y.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out the issue, when you add a drawer_layout to your project you need to put everything that was previously in the activity into the content_frame or it will just treat the drawer as a normal element eating inputs behind it.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `elevation` attribute of views. This allows views to change their `z` position so they are drawn above other views and drop shadow despite being below in view hierarchy.

It seems Your recyclerView items use `cardView` with default elevation of `4dp` while navigationDrawer has less (I think `2dp`?).

Comment: Setting the elevation of the recyclerview to 0 did nothing visible, and setting the elevation of the drawerlayout to more than that of the recyclerview causes the recyclerview to be immobile again. I was setting the elevations using android:elevation="4dp". Also setting the elevation to 0dp works but -1dp stops movement so I'm not sure the cardviews actually are raised?

Comment: I didn't mean elevation of recyclerView itself, I meant elevation of cards that are within `viewHolder` layout. See if anything changes if you use `app:cardElevation=0dp`.

Comment: The drawer is behind images at the bottom of the screen as well as the recyclerview, so I think I need to elevate the nav? Also changing the card elevation didn't help.